# SSH AuthorizedKeysFile not accepting multiple files

Tags: linux, ssh

According to this reported [BUG 1405158](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1405158) some Linux versions will not accept multiple authorized key files. This is a problem as I am connecting to a server with a non-root user. If I add that user key to the main authorized_keys file in /root/.ssh permission is denied for that user, as you would expect.

Is there any quick way around this. The suggestion at the bottom of the bug report to add a root application for this purpose is rather painful.

So I just want to be able to login to the user folder from another server using key authentication, this should be easy, and I have it working fine on other versions already.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you please try to explain your original problem a bit better? I doubt that whatever problem you want to solve is affected by this issue.

Comment: The login is to copy files from one server to another securely. This should work and works on other versions I have tested it, I don't want to undo all that work for one particular version of Linux.

Comment: I don't get why you need the ability to specify multiple key files. You can have multiple keys in a single file. Again, I believe that the bug you refer to is irrelevant to your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "main authorized_keys file in /root/.ssh". It is just the authorized_keys file for the user "root".

If you log in with the name "user", than you have to place the key in the directory ~user/.ssh . Why would you need to specify multiple files?

Comment: The confusion seems to be that the default is `#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys` this was allowing logins for root even though authorized_keys with the correct key was in `/root/..ssh/authorized_keys` not `.ssh/authorized_keys`. I have now set the configuration to just `%h/.ssh/authorized_keys` and it is working for both users, so problem solved.